# Missing (or hidden) RVM environment when running irb

Tags: ruby, rvm, irb

When I try to start irb, I get the error `ERROR: Missing RVM environment file: '/home/tom/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p180'`

The funny thing is, my home directory is thomas, not tom -- RVM is using my home directory name from before I had to do a reinstall of Ubuntu and on a whim renamed myself. There is no file at `/home/thomas/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p180`. I tried uninstalling RVM using these commands (http://www.mkoby.com/2011/06/03/completely-removing-rvm/) and the error remains. I don't think that my .irbrc file is doing anything fishy:

```
IRB.conf[:PROMPT][:CUSTOM] = {
  :PROMPT_I => "%3n :: ",
  :PROMPT_S => "%3n %l>> ",
  :PROMPT_C => "%3n .. ",
  :PROMPT_N => "%3n .. ",
  :RETURN => "    => %s\n"
}
IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :CUSTOM
IRB.conf[:AUTO_INDENT] = true

# Stuff to load
require 'pp'

require 'irb/completion'
require 'irb/ext/save-history'
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 100
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb-history"
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following

```
echo $HOME   -- should point to the correct home directory

which rvm    -- should pick rvm from the correct home directory

which irb    -- should pick irb from the correct location

gem env      -- check if the gem paths are correctly set.
```

Btw are your rvm commands running fine. 
Try doing

```
rvm list
rvm use 1.9.2
```

Comment: Well that's interesting. The first three commands look ok, giving /home/thomas and /home/thomas/bin/irb and /home/thomas/bin/rvm. The `gem env` command gives the familiar error, `ERROR: Missing RVM environment file: '/home/tom/.rvm/environments/ruby-1.9.2-p180'`. And the two rvm commands result in an infinite loop of `/home/thomas/bin/rvm: line 49: /home/thomas/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory`